# How does this collision detection work (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, collision, detection

Can you please explain, so that an idiot could understand, how this collision detection works for a 2d brick-breaker game? I'm having trouble visualizing how it works. There is a paddle hitting the ball and the ball breaks bricks, the collision detection in this code is for the ball bouncing off the walls.

```
if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
}
if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
    dy = -dy;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you're satisfied with any of the answers, please accept and up vote.

Answer (score 0):

If the next position (currentPosition (`x|y`) + direction (`dx|dy`))  is farther than the available space (all the space minus ball's radius), or less than the ball's radius, then invert the direction.
In the first case, we are too much on right or bottom, on the second one, we are too much on the left or top.

So coming next `x += dx` or `y += dy` actually goes backward and never hits the wall.

*By the way, for realistic hit, you'd want to get by how much it should have gone into the wall, to get the correct position after bounce.*

Comment: Ok thanks that helps. When you say "So coming next x += dx actually goes backward and never hits the wall."  Is that what x + dx < ballRadius means? Why do I need both x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius and x + dx < ballRadius for this to work?

Comment: Because you need to check if it's too much on the left of too much on the right. When I say "next `x += dx`", I'm talking about something that you didn't show in your question but which is either a few lines before or after the ones you extracted (maybe written `x = x + dx;`)

Comment: How come x + dx < ballRadius can't be used for both sides?

Comment: "x + dx < ballRadius" is checking if the position of the ball after the next tick/step is at least ballRadius away from the left side (x == 0). You do use similar logic for the right side but for the right side you want to check how far the ball is from the right side (x == canvas.width) so you can't use the exact same equation.

Comment: Let me put it another way. `x + dx < ballRadius` is really `x + dx < leftSide + ballRadius` but since `leftSide == 0` that term can be omitted. The equation for the right side is almost the same `x + dx > rightSide - ballRadius` where `rightSide == canvas.width` but since `rightSide` isn't `0` it can't be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Both if statements are the same so I'll just explain the first one.

```
if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
    dx = -dx;
}
```

is the same as

```
const centerOfBallAfterNextTick = x + dx;
const willHitLeftWall = centerOfBallAfterNextTick - ballRadius < 0;
const willHitRightWall = centerOfBallAfterNextTick + ballRadius > canvas.width;
if (willHitRightWall || willHitLeftWall) {
    dx = -dx; //start moving in the opposite direction
}
```